# opencv core.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I am trying to use opencv in android native c++, but I got compilation errors as title. here is my code

in cpp

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
```

in android.mk

```
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE := STATIC
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES := on   
include fullpathToOpencv/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCv.mk
```

in project properties->c/c++ general->paths and symbols, I added

```
fullpathtoOpencv/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include
fullpathtoOpencv/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv
```

Btw, I am using eclipse 4.2 on osx.
Does anybody have idea how to solve this problem, Thanks.

Below is my full android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

OPENCV_LIB_TYPE := STATIC
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES := on   
include ../../dev/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCv.mk

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := CameraPreviewSample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := CameraPreviewSample.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Please edit the question. Add a separator below the existing text (you can find it on the editor tool bar). Then add your full `Android.mk`.

Comment: Ok, I added my full Android.mk